Fetch works but http post doesn't in Angular ts file, what am I doing wrong?
I have this fetch statement below that works fine in my .ts file.


const fileResult = await fetch(environment.stripeFileUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + environment.stripePublishableKey
  },
  body: data,
});
const fileData = await fileResult.json();



But when I write it like this below I get a status 401, status Text Ok, but an  error that says my API key is incorrect.
Am I plugging in the header incorrectly?
New code that doesn't work


this.accountService.getStripeIdentityToken(data).subscribe(response => {
  if (response.error) {
    this.showError(response.error.message);
  } else {
    this.outputFile.emit({
      file: response.id,
      description: null
    });
  }
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}).add(() => {
  this.loading(false);
});



getStripeIdentityToken(data: any) {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${environment.stripePublishableKey}`);
  // I also tried below with same error about the incorrect API key
  // headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer pk_test_fTr...BVLn9e6`);

  return this.http.post<any>(environment.stripeFileUrl, data, {
    headers
  });
}




Hi, did you check the network request sent with the correct API key in the request header from the Browser DevTools? Just to confirm that possibly there is a HTTP Interceptor that override the request headers.

Hi Yong Shun. I can see that the bearer key is being removed and replaced by a my Jwt interceptor as it thinks I'm only calling my server. Do you know if there is a way to disable it for this single call?

Can you help your code for your Jwt Interceptor?

Ah I figured it out, I just needed to check to see if I was calling my server, if not don't set the Bearer key as my token and use the Stripe key as the Bearer instead.

In your JwtInterceptor, you can check and use the request header containing the "Authorization" key pair if it does exist.
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Get default auth token from the service.
    const authToken = /* Default token from service/local storage etc. */

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 
        request.headers.get('Authorization') ?? authToken)
    });

    // send cloned request with header to the next handler.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

